# Json Schema Validation - Referencing Sub Schema

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I am trying to validate json data, against a schema that has the following structure:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$id": "https://foo.bar/my.schema.json",
  "$def": {
    "parentType": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "child": {
          "$ref": "#/$def/childType"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "child"
      ]
    },
    "childType": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "parent": {
      "$ref": "#/$def/parentType"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "parent"
  ]
}
```

Following is the json data:

```
{
  "parent": {
    "child": {
      "name": "aaa",
    }  
  }
}
```

How do I ensure via json schema validation, that the value for the following field **/parent/child/name** is either **aaa** or **bbb**?

I don't want to add a restriction to the childType definition, as I want to keep the type definition of childType "generic", and add a restriction later on outside of `$def` block. This way I can use the same childType for a different scenario, where the `name` might not be "aaa" or "bbb".

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't impossible to do, but I don't know if it will be done in a way which is useful for you. Can you maybe explain WHY you want to do this? What's the use case / requirement for this? What are the actual values and why are they limited to two strings?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what I am trying to do is to put the `$def`s in a separate JSON file (all the "generic" types) and have a separate JSON file for each scenario I want to validate. And that scenario might require "aaa" or "bbb" and have the other "properties" for the childType optional, and another scenario needs me to validate for different properties (which were optional for the first case). This way I can reuse the types in the scenario-specific schema, instead of copying-pasting them everywhere. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using draft `2019-09`, you can use `$ref` alongside other keywords.
This isn't allowed in earlier drafts such as `draft-07`.

For example, rather than having...

```
"properties": {
    "parent": {
      "$ref": "#/$def/parentType"
    }
  },
```

You can have...

```
  "properties": {
    "parent": {
      "$ref": "#/$def/parentType",
      "enum": ["aaa", "bbb"]
    }
  }
```

If you want to use multiple references, you'll need to do them as subschemas wrapped in an `allOf`.